# Digital Output (MCU) to 2 other Devices with Voltage Divider inbetween

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, voltage-divider

A digital signal (from an MCU) should go to 2 other devices (ports configured as input). The output voltage is about 3.3V. The input voltage on the other devices should be between 2V and 3V (same devices, directly to transistor, no pullups etc.). I would like to use a voltage divider (e.g. 100/300 ohm). Options are:

a) split digital output signal first and apply for every input a voltage divider (in sum 2, uses 4 resistors)

b) use a voltage divider on digital output and then split signal for 2 inputs (needs only 1 voltage divider with 2 resistors)

c) better ideas?

Which option is the way to go? Any advatages over the other one?

PS.: I am new to electronics.

Comment: That sounds weird.. what are the "other divices"?

Comment: 2 cameras that needs to be triggered in the same moment. Trigger input on the camera side is a GPIO. MCU output is 3.3V (high) but camera spec says that no more than 3V should be used.

Comment: Are you  sure that's a hi-low logic voltage though, or is it a voltage range for a high signal. Linking in some specs or even a part number would help.

Comment: Voltage range for the input is from 0-3V, high is 2-3V and low is 0-0.8V.

Comment: That's what I though... You should not need to manipulate the 3.3V signal then... Just use as is.

Comment: Trevor, can you explain your reasoning? knivil clearly stated that the specs says "no more than 3V", then how is a 3.3V fine to use?

Comment: @user2913869, Pretty sure the actual value will be Vcc + a bit if you dig deep enough into the spec. You could limit the high with a shotky but you wont get much closer than 3.3 anyway. And you will not actually get 3.3 out of the driving device.

Comment: knivil, don't listen to Trevor. He is making assumptions ("Pretty sure"). It is a very bad idea to disobey the part's specifications. You must always follow the rules of the specs, or it is not guaranteed to work. Even worse, you would risk damaging/ruining your part. Voltage divide the output using a resistor divider. I recommend one resistor divider and then split the output to tie into both of them. Consider the input impedance of the cameras in your resistor equation. The reason for 1 vs divider vs 2 is that the resistor tolerances may make the 2 cameras trigger at different times.

Comment: As @user2913869 pointed out I am assuming the device has the normal over Vcc tolerance which will be buried deeper in the specs. The front page specs are always a general guide. If you have them, look closer to verify. I would NOT however recommend resistor dividers. Doing to simply leaves you open to noise problems, especially at camara frequencies.